# Type cast variable in groovy depending on another variables class?

Tags: groovy

e.g

```
def a = "567"
def b = 0
```

now I want to check if 'a' can be cast to int (as class of b is int) ?

I can do

```
def x =  a as int
```

but doing

```
def x = a as b.getClass()
```

gives error.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say you have:

```
def a = '567'
def type = Integer
```

You can [use `asType` to do](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#asType%28java.lang.Class%29):

```
assert a.asType( type ) == 567
```

Or if you want to use the type of the other variable;

```
def a = '567'
def b = 0

assert a.asType( b.getClass() ) == 567
```